# replace null with blank in array tree recursively php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to replace all the null values in array with the blank values or empty string recursively.

Currrently my array is looking like this,which is perfect in structure, i want to replace every null value from it by empty string.

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 28
                    [name] => ABC
                    [goal] => 
                    [currency] => 
                    [images] => 
                    [start] => 1446159600
                    [stop] => 1446246000
                )
            [1] => Array
                 (
                    [id] => 29
                    [name] => XYZ
                    [goal] => 
                    [currency] => 
                    [images] => 
                    [start] => 1446159600
                    [stop] => 1446246000
                )
        )
)
```

Please show me shortest way to replace it.

Comment: Take a look at: [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Comment: Where do you see null values? I don't see any, because you are using the wrong debug print function. Try `var_dump`.

Comment: It is there, showing NULL values when i am using this array for JSON parsing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out by Rizier123, you can do this with [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

```
function replaceNullValueWithEmptyString(&$value) {
    $value = $value === null ? "" : $value;
}

array_walk_recursive($array, "replaceNullValueWithEmptyString");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result array if you using the **array_map();** function.
Here is example code.

```
$item = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana','c' => 'rama', 'd' => 'lingam','e' => '', 'f' => '');

function addNull($n)
{    
    if($n=='')
        return('NULL');
    else
        return($n);
}

$result_array = array_map("addNull", $item);

print_r($result_array);
```